# find command exec {} matching folder empty - Fish shell

Tags: shell, find, exec, fish

When running a simple `find` and attempting to `-exec` some commands on the result I get an empty value for `{}`

For example:

```
$ find ~/folder-with-files -exec echo {} \;
```

on a folder containing 3 files returns empty

```
$
$
$
```

I'm using the Fish shell on MacOS.

Comment: You're expecting bash behavior. But note that zsh, csh, ksh, and bash all behave differently with respect to brace expansion. See https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/1109 where we're discussing how we want fish to behave although consensus has been reached that a freestanding `{}` should be left alone, ala bash.

Answer (score 3):

When using Fish shell the `{}` variable must be wrapped in quotes `"{}"`

```
find ~/folder-with-files -exec echo "{}" \;
```

Returns correctly in both `bash` and `fish` shells

```
$ file1.txt
$ file2.txt
$ file3.txt
```